# how to bring change in TextView ,when simultaneously making change/write in EditView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

When user write any number in the `EditView` a corresponding change must reflect in the `TextView`. example, if user gives 10 input in `Editview` , a change must reflect in the `TextView`(logic: [user_input_number]*10) as user writing.

I tried this code, the change is not reflecting always.

```
 final EditText eT10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.N_onezero);

 final TextView tV10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.A_onezero);

    eT10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String S10 = eT10.getText().toString();
            tV10.setText(S10);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TextChangedListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` and apply your logic to `TextView` inside `afterTextChanged`.

```
eT10.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //You can also apply your logic here instead of afterTextChanged
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String S10 = s.toString();
        tV10.setText(S10);
    }
});
```